# Delay the execution of all unit tests in XCTest

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, testing, xctest

I need my unit tests to wait for our sub-systems to initialize, which usually takes a few seconds. In order to wait for this, I can do the following in a test

```
- (void)testReverseActionWithOffset
{
    XCTestExpectation *expectation = [self expectationWithDescription:@"High Expectations"];

    // Wait for proper initialization of Realm and CrimsonObject system...
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 3 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
```

The problem is, using this technique, I have to do this wait in every single test method. This leads to there being a two second delay between each test even after the system is booted up. Because the test methods run in an undetermined order, I can't put the delay in just one method. What is the correct way to handle this under XCTest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Because the test methods run in an undetermined order, I can't put the delay in just one method

Anything that needs to be done between *every* test can be done in either [`-setUp`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest/xctest/1500341-setup?language=objc) or [`-tearDown`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest/xctest/1500463-teardown?language=objc).

If you need to do something once per `XCTestCase`, you can use either of the class methods [`+setUp`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest/xctestcase/1496262-setup?language=objc) or [`+tearDown`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest/xctestcase/1496280-teardown?language=objc). The first runs before any tests are run, and the latter after all tests.

You can do a non-blocking wait in any of those methods by spinning the run loop:

```
+ (void)setUp
{
    while( /* subsystems not ready */ ){
        [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1]];
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is, as far as I could see in my testing, there was no way to delay using these methods. Expectations didn't seem to have an effect and if you flat out sleep(), it delays the main thread so my loading doesn't initialize (which is what I was waiting for in the first place). If you know a way around this, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: To do a non-blocking wait, you can spin the run loop until your condition is met: `while( /* subsystems not ready */ ) {
        [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.5]];
    }` I should note that I can't help but feeling that I'm answering your question at the expense of solving your problem. I'm not quite sure what the true correct answer is here.

Comment: Didn't realize that you could continue on with the main thread from within the thread! This works great. Could you add this into the answer and I'll accept?
+ (void)setUp
{
    while(<SystemIsStartingUp>)
    {
        [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:.1f]];
    }
}

Comment: nm on that request! Didn't realize I had the permission to edit other peoples answers. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad I could help. One small note on your code: `NSTimeInterval` is a `double`, not a `float`. The `f` suffix is not correct in this case.